# I have a error called "name 'CustomUser' is not defined"

Tags: django-custom-user

#This is my models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

## Create your models here.

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
USER = (
(1,'HOD'),
(2, 'STAFF'),
(3, 'STUDENT'),
)
user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER,max_length=50,default=1)
profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/profile_pic')

## this is my views

@login_required(login_url='/')
def Profile(request):
user = CustomUser.objects.get(id = request.user.id)

```
context = {
    "user":user,
}
return render(request,'Profile.html' ,context)
```

## my settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'apps.CustomUser'

Comment: did you have an app named `apps`? and make sure the model `CustomUser` is inside that app.

Comment: yes my app name is apps and i have include it in models in apps and register it

Comment: you need to import `CustomUser` in **views.py**

Comment: in views.py you need to add `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model` 
`CustomUser = get_user_model()`

Comment: yes that really works .. Thank you so much